# socket.io two connect event

Tags: socket.io, chat

I'm trying basic socket io example provided in the link :

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/
https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example

However I have added an on connect event in index.html just to check if client gets connected

```
var socket = io();
      // Other Code

   socket.on("connect", function(){
        console.log("ON Connect Event  : ");
  });



 socket.on("chat message", function(){
    // Other Code
  });
```

The example runs fine, But when I disconnect my internet and connect it again;  Connect event is triggered twice.
I could see `"ON Connect Event  : "` two times
On debugging on chrome Developer tool I found out that connect event listener is added 1st by

```
var socket = io();  

connect:Array[1]
```

and then 2nd connect event is added by

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('ON Connect Event  :  ');
  })

connect:Array[2]
```

Because of this there are 2 event Listener for connect event.
Is this the correct behavior??
I want to write some custom logic in socket connect fucntion, But then I don't want it to be called twice after Internet Disconnect-Connect.
Is there any workaround??

Comment: What code generates this `connect:Array[2]`?  Are you keeping track of your own array of sockets?  If so, you have to remove sockets on the `disconnect` event or don't keep your own array, just use the one socket.io already has.

Comment: No I'm not keep track of any array.  I added the socket variable to watch. Socket object has _callbacks which  contains all the event listener and from there I got 'connect:Array[2]'.  Its not even about disconnect. When you load the page and debug the socket variable, you'll 2 connect event.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/474
there are quiet a few possible workarounds for your issue, for example: disable force auto re connect flag, and manage it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I'm changing the code structure :)